# Hide HTML5 video in UIWebView if it cannot be played

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, html5-video

I have a UIWebView that contains a HTML5 video. The `SRC` of the video is dynamic, and uses HTTP Live Streaming. If, for whatever reason, the video cannot be played, the user is presented with the "play-with-a-slash-though-it" icon, indicating it cannot be played. I'd like to handle this situation by hiding the video player and presenting a message to the user instead. Are there any callbacks that I can subscribe to that will allow me to achieve this?

**UPDATE**

Thanks to codeghost's answer, I was able to resolve my problem. However, I thought it would be useful for future readers to see a code example:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <video id='video' width='640' height='480' controls='controls' preload='none' autoplay='autoplay'>
            <source src='http://some.video.com'/>
            Your browser does not support the video tag.
        </video>

        <script type='text/javascript'>
            var video = document.getElementById('video')
            video.addEventListener('error', function(event) { 
                if(event.type == "error")
                {
                    alert("There was an error getting the video.");
                }
            }, true);

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this in the web page by adding a javascript handler for error event on the video tag.

Comment: While I agree with you and this is the method I would generally use, what about detecting whether the video can/cannot be played?

Comment: Not an HTML5 expert, when would a video not be playable but no error event raised? I've not experienced it